# In Python, how to know if a function is getting a variable or an object?

Tags: python-3.x

How can you test whether your function is getting `[1,2,4,3]` or `l`?

That might be useful to decide whether you want to return, for example, an ordered list or replace it in place.

For example, if it gets `[1,2,4,3]` it should return `[1,2,3,4]`. If it gets `l`, it should link the ordered list to `l` and do not return anything.

Comment: *Explicit is better than implicit*. `sort` and `sorted` exist for a reason.

Comment: @noisypixy: the sort bit in my question is just an example. It could well be deleting an element, or inverting it, or duplicating each element.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. What I mean is that you can save yourself some future headaches by keeping functions as simple and obvious as possible. It's easy to forget subtle behavior differences like this.

Comment: The built-in ``isinstance()`` function is your friend: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: Tonechas: sorry that's useless here. Did you understand the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell the difference in any reasonable way; you could do terrible things with the `gc` module to count references, but that's not a reasonable way to do things. There is no difference between an anonymous object and a named variable (aside from the reference count), because it will be named no matter what when received by the function; "variables" aren't really a thing, Python has "names" which reference objects, with the object utterly unconcerned with whether it has named or unnamed references.

Make a consistent API. If you need to have it operate both ways, either have it do both things (mutate in place and return the mutated copy for completeness), or make two distinct APIs (one of which can be written in terms of the other, by having the mutating version used to implement the return new version by making a local copy of the argument, passing it to the mutating version, then returning the mutated local copy).